# Dynamic Linkify Text in ListView - Error : no intent found with data : specified url

Tags: android, listview, linkify

i am creating a **listview**.
in that list each item has **text view**.
and in text views i am defining **linkify texts** based on data **from the web service**..

now when i **click on that** linkify text i am getting **error** like

```
09-21 20:27:38.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(766): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=\"ticbeat.com/socialmedia/fa…" (has extras)
```

please help me solving this problem..
any answer with solution will highly appreciated.

Update:

Code:

```
if(urlentities[position]!=null && dpurlentities[position]!=null)
            holder.twtdata.setText(Html.fromHtml(timelines[position].replace(urlentities[position],"<a href=\\\""+dpurlentities[position]+"\">"+urlentities[position]+"</a>")));
```

Comment: @Venky i use this code in my adapter class to set the text of text view

Comment: Is there any web browser to the device/emulator? Have you tried to another device or emulator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look like you need to put `http://` at the beginning of that URL.  Without the protocol specifier Android appears to assume "content://" is the intended url type.

Answer (score 0):

Linkify by default opens the default browser (new activity). I'm guessing you pass `getBaseContext()`  as  context  to the `TextView(Context context)`. You have to pass the activity as Context for that to work by default. If you are concerned about memory leaks you can try `getApplicationContext()` but haven't tested it.

The best way to handle that is to create a listener at the TextView fired on `onclick()` of the span . Your activity (the one that created the textView() catches that listener and then the activity opens the browser.  [Here](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/) you can see how to make your own listener

Another way to do that is to implement a WebView in you layout and all you have to do from the textView is to show that webView with the link clicked. getBaseContext() can do that.

Comment: i am using Custome Adapter to fill data in List, and calling adapter like this adapter = new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this); but still getting the same error..do i need to define anything that how the link should execute...I UPDATED MY QUESTION TO SHOW CODE..PLZ CHECK ONCE

Comment: thank you my problem was my mistake..but that knowledge of passing context to adapter also was really very helpful