# Link on a Android textView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to put a link on a `textview`, but when I click this link the application breaks!! This is my code:

```
final TextView msg = (TextView)view_aux.findViewById(R.id.accordion_msg);
msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(dbStructure.getMsg()));
msg.setTypeface(tF);
msg.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
msg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Where `dbStructure.getMsg()` returns a `String`. This String could be something like:

```
< a href="/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html">RelativeLayout< /a>
```

lets child views specify their position relative to the parent view or to each other (specified by ID). So you can align two elements by right border, or make one below another, centered in the screen, centered left, and so on.

It seems nice, but the app stops when I press it.

**EDIT**
The error thrown ActivityNotFoundException.

Comment: what error does it show in the logcat

Comment: ActivityNotFoundException... sorry, but I swear that did not appear before on the AndroidStudio logcat...

Comment: Try adding `http://` as a url prefix

Comment: Please show your Android Manifest

Comment: You probably are missing something in `AndroidManifest`... check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121450/activitynotfoundexception)

Comment: Check if the activity you try to open is there.If you are trying to open the link in browser check if  exist or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502306/dynamic-linkify-text-in-listview-error-no-intent-found-with-data-specified

Comment: Sorry @skizo... I don´t see your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for every one... the problem is (as @Antonio @danidee @TheRedFox and @Arslan say) the format of the url... it doesn´t start with http. 
With permission from you all, I am going to answer my own question:

```
final TextView msg = (TextView)view_aux.findViewById(R.id.accordion_msg);
String msg_text = dbStructure.getMsg();
if(msg_text.contains("href=\"")) {
    String[] msg_aux = msg_text.split("<a href=\"");
    if (!msg_aux[1].toLowerCase().startsWith("http"))
        msg_aux[1] = "href=\"http://" + msg_aux[1];
    else
        msg_aux[1] = "href=\"" + msg_aux[1];
    msg_text = msg_aux[0] + msg_aux[1];
}
msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg_text));
msg.setTypeface(tF);
msg.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
msg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Thank you.

**EDIT** on the code, these lines:

```
else
    msg_aux[1] = "href=\"" + msg_aux[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

the link you are trying to open is broken

```
/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html
```

there is nothing corresponding to the above link.

replace it with the proper url like this

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html
```

Comment: How would that help solving ActivityNotFoundException ?